# Python using daterange to name the file (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
months = pd.date_range(startdate, enddate, freq="MS")

for start, end in zip(months[:-1], months[1:]):
 predata = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(features) 
 datafixed  = pd.DataFrame(predata,index=fixed_col_df.index,columns=col)
 fixed_col_df[col] = datafixed[col] 
 fixed_col_df['Month'] = int(start.strftime('%m'))
 start_time = int(start.strftime('%m'))
 fixed_col_df[(fixed_col_df.index >= start) & (fixed_col_df.index < 
 end)].to_excel(f"C:\\xxxx\\xxx\\xxxx\\xx\\xxxx\\xxx\\xxxxxx\\ 
 {start_time}.xlsx", sheet_name="Data")
```

i would like to ask 2 questions:
Firstly, how can i name the files with the daterange,For example,2019-01 to 2022-01 , 2019-01 the number of month would be 1 , 2019-01 would be 2
2021-01 would be 13 ,2022-12 would be number 36.

Secondly,i would like to set the number of month to the dataframe's index

i try it for 2 days,but i still cannot fix it
thanks for answering my questions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXueJ.png)

Comment: Hi Wilson, can you share minimal reproducible example with the code, that is actually required here

Comment: i have no idea what code is required , coz the problems is not in the code .

Comment: you already have the code, when you are running it what error are you getting

Comment: 2021-01 should be 25 and 2022-12 should be 48, no?

Comment: yes @Corralien, you got the point

Answer (score 0):

If your index is already a `DatetimeIndex`, use:

```
# Your code
predata = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit_transform(features) 
datafixed  = pd.DataFrame(predata, index=fixed_col_df.index, columns=col)
fixed_col_df[col] = datafixed[col]

# Add 'Month' column
fixed_col_df['Month'] = fixed_col_df.groupby(df.to_period('M'), sort=True).ngroup()

# Export to files
for month, subdf in fixed_col_df.groupby('Month'):
    subdf.to_excel(f"{month}.xlsx", sheet_name='Data')
```

Note: if `index` is not a `DatetimeIndex`, convert it with `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
```

Comment: @Wilson. Does it solve your problem?

Comment: emmm there is a  problem , an error popped up :  unsupported Type Int64Index

Comment: What is `fixed_col_df.index`? Please update your post with the output of `fixed_col_df.index[:5]`

Comment: i have updated a photo ,which is fixed_col_df

Comment: Can you try `fixed_col_df['Month'] = fixed_col_df.groupby(pd.to_datetime(fixed_col_df.index).to_period('M'), sort=True).ngroup()`

Comment: thanks for answering patiently Corralien